# How can I get the thumbnail from a WP_Post object?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to Loop over a bunch of pages under a certain taxonomy. The looping part works great, and I get all of the pages I need (nicely wrapped in `WP_Post` objects).

However, now I'm facing a different kind of problem. I want to include the page's thumbnail as set in the editor. I've tried any combination of `get`, `the`, `thumbnail`, `featured`, `image`, `_`, `-`, I could think of, to no avail.

The `WP_Post` object is rather new, and **[documentation is lacking](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Post)**.

Can anyone shed light on this mystery? My goal is to eventually show a bunch of `<figure>` elements, containing an image, a title, and a short description of each object.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following is just a proof of concept in form of shortcode. It dumps a code block with all posts that have a [Featured Image](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails).

Function reference: [`has_post_thumbnail`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_post_thumbnail), [`get_the_post_thumbnail`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail)

```
add_shortcode( 'all-post-thumbs', 'so_14007170_dump_post_thumbs' );

function so_14007170_dump_post_thumbs( $atts, $content ) 
{
    // Query
    $posts = get_posts( array(
        'post_type'    => 'post',
        'numberposts'  => -1,
        'post_status'  => 'publish'
    ) );

    // Build an array of post thumbnails
    $thumbs = array();
    foreach( $posts as $post)
    {
        if( has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID) )
            $thumbs[] = array( $post->post_title, htmlentities(get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ) );
    }

    // Build output and return
    $echo = '<pre>'. print_r( $thumbs, true ) . '</pre>';
    return $echo;
}
```

**Result in frontend:**

> [image: var dump]

**Posts with featured image:**

> [image]

Comment: Aha! This is what I was looking for! `get_the_post_thumbnail` accepts an ID! (I really hate WordPress). Thank you! +25!

Comment: @developerbmw, what commas? :P

Comment: @brasofilo much better :D

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what do you want but if you want to get all images of a certain page then you can use

```
$parent='your page id';
$args=array(
    'post_parent' => $parent,
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'post_mime_type' => 'image',
    'orderby' => 'menu_order',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'numberposts' => -1 
);
$images = get_children($args);
```

You can paste this code in your loop and if you provide the appropriate `page_id` as `parent` then you'll get all images as an array in the `$images` and can run a loop.

Read more [at Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_children).

### Update:

To get only the featured image you can use

```
echo get_the_post_thumbnail('page id here', 'thumbnail');
```

Read more [at Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail).

Comment: Is the "featured image" I select found among those? If so, is it possible to only get that one?

Comment: Do you want to get only featured image of the page ?

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    // stuff before thumbnail

    $thumbnail_args = array();

    // insert whatever thumbnail args you want

    echo get_the_post_thumbnail();

    // stuff after thumbnail

endwhile; else:

    echo "<h2>Sorry, nothing to see here.</h2>";
endif
```

Unfortunately, the WP_Post methods are named really poorly. Most methods which interact with the Post need to have some arrangement of '_' and 'post' added to them.

Comment: (un?)fortunately, I'm not using the global loop, but an inner loop, generated by WP_Query. Thanks anyway :)